# Passing Environment variables to React application from Package.json

Tags: reactjs, npm, environment-variables, create-react-app

following this article https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/environments-in-create-react-app.html

I am trying to add an environment variable to my react app which I have created using create react app. so my build command looks like below

```
 "build": "REACT_APP_SECRET_CODE=123 react-scripts build",
```

while I try to run this build command in my Visual studio code terminal via

```
npm run build
```

it gives me the error that `REACT_APP_SECRET_CODE` is not recognized as an internal or external command.

How would i pass the environment variable in `package.json and build my app and access the variable value in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it in a clean way (imo) using [better-npm-run](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-npm-run) package

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "better-npm-run": "~0.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "better-npm-run build",
  },
  "betterScripts": {
    "build": {
      "command": "react-scripts build",
      "env": {
        "REACT_APP_SECRET_CODE": "123"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

there are more advanced usage for this library, which I think might help you in the long term on your project

Comment: well that worked but ... I have to host this application through aws amplify .. and i want host it for multiple regions with different REST API ends .. i thought i would pass rest api url endpoint in my environment variable and use in my application .. well i can do this right now , but i really wanted a way for client to change the variable values in the build settings and deploy the application for multiple regions ... is it possible anyway ?

Comment: @umer yeap, that use case is common and is definitely possible. Depending on your CI tools, if it is google cloud, you can use multiple `.yaml` file to define different values, and choose which to deploy dynamically

Comment: from inside .yaml file i want to pass this environment variable so that my react app can access it .. how would i pass this from .yaml file , this is aws cloudformation and it contains the build settings of my react application

Comment: I'm not very familiar with aws to answer your question, there should be a way if you search aws documentation.

Comment: if you really want to use the command line, maybe you can try to install `cross-env` npm package, then you can run `cross-env REACT_APP_SECRET_CODE=123 react-scripts build`

Comment: @JeeMok How would I go about injected the env variables from the `.yaml` file into my react app?

Comment: there are other better ways to inject env variables depending on your use case; if you're using `.yaml` I assume you probably have CI/CD setup? if so then you should add it into your pipeline or inside the config yaml files

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to install any other library. You can pass environment variable to  yarn or npm command like this:

```
"scripts": {
 "start": "breact-scripts start",
 "start:env": "REACT_APP_ABC=xyz yarn start",
}
```

Note: Remember to put prefix "REACT_APP_" in your environment variable otherwise React won't allow it to use in app.